# Angular animations without ng-animate, possible?

Tags: javascript, animation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

For some circumstances I use **angular's** version **1.0.6**. And there's no amazing built-in ng-animate...

My question is - do you have some examples of page transitions with custom directives?

In my case, I'm fetching data from the server, and when I fetched data I need to show `div` items smoothly on the page (smth like transiotion from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`).

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for examples is not a good question for SO.  Please post a practical *problem* you are having and where you need assistance.

Comment: i mean some experience sharing, i shortly described what is the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a directive called ng-show-anim bind the myVariable from parent scope to directive scope.

   `<div ng-show-anim="myVariable" />`
2. On the directive, add a $watch on 'myVariable'
3. On the $watch function, use Jquery animation to show that div.

Comment: looks promising, will try

Answer (score 0):

You could use [angular ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq)'s jQuery passthrough feature and bind custom animations as directives to your element.
Here's a very basic example :

```
<ul ng-model="items">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ui-jq="fadeIn"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i don't like the idea of using jquery in my case, cause in most cases it's enough to use angular's jqLite